# Flask for loop issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests

This is my `dir.py` for flask

```py
import requests

def dir(domain):
    paths = ['/test','/html','/go','/.git']

    for path in paths:
        path = path.strip()
        url = 'http://'+domain+path

        result = requests.get(url)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            return url

dir("localhost")
```

This is `run.py`

```py
@app.route('/brute', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def brute():
    erroro = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        domain = None
        try:
            if request.form["domain"] == "":
                erroro += ("<p>{!r} Input Empty</p>").format(request.form["domain"])
            else:
                domain = request.form["domain"]
        except:
            erroro += ("<p>{!r} Input Empty</p>").format(request.form["domain"])

        if domain is not None:
            brute_res = brute_admin(domain)
        return render_template("brute_result.html", brute_res = brute_res) 
    return render_template('brute.html').format(erroro=erroro)
```

Now the problem is i am trying to print the url list in webpage like:

http://localhost/test

http://localhost/html

but it's just printing the first url with path, i have tried others way but no luck.What i can do now.Also this process taking few time and and result not showing until it finish the process is there any that i can do it on background and later i can download the url list which is validate as i coded in `dir.py` if status_code == 200 then return url.If there any alternative way to do this process please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: `return url` - that's your problem. The loop ends as soon as you `return`.

Comment: BTW it's a bad idea to reuse builtin names like `dir`

Comment: if i didn't return it then print func working in console.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `url` after the first time you get a 200 response.

Try something like this:

```
urls = []
for path in paths:
    path = path.strip()
    url = 'http://'+domain+path
    result = requests.get(url)
    if result.status_code == 200:
         urls.append(url)
return urls
```

Collect all the urls you want to return and return the list outside the for loop

Comment: i used it already but not working it just showing on html render ['http://localhost/.git/'] only single response